# java file compile issue in php windows

Tags: java, php, scripting, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying to run java file in PHP file.
Server: WAMP

Configured JAVA path globally and also tried using manual command.
in php.ini file :

```php
safe_mode = disable
safe_mode_exec_dir = off
```

HelloWorld.java

```java
/* This is a simple Java program. FileName : "HelloWorld.java". */
class HelloWorld { 
    // Your program begins with a call to main(). 
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window. 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
    } 
}
```

test.php

```php
//exec("set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin", $output,$return_var);Tried this

//shell_exec();also tried
exec("java -version 2>&1", $output1, $return_var);
var_dump($output1);
//exec("javac E:\wamp\www\my\HelloWorld.java 2>&1", $output, $return_var);tried abs path
exec("javac HelloWorld.java 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
```

output1 var dump Result

> array (size=3)
>   0 => string 'java version "1.8.0_201"' (length=24)
>   1 => string 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)' (length=53)
>   2 => string 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)' (length=64)

output vardump result

> array (size=2)
>   0 => string ''javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' (length=61)
>   1 => string 'operable program or batch file.' (length=31)

if java is installed then how could this happen?

Comment: It means you have a JRE (Java *runtime*), not a JDK (Java Development Kit). So you have the `java` command, but not the `javac` command which is a development tool.

Comment: Or the JDK bin directory is not in your path.

Comment: Same command running perfectly in Windows command (cmd)

Comment: @abhichavda Have you tried javac.exe rather than javac?

Comment: @mwarren can you elaborate ?

Comment: I assumed you were running on Windows and just wondered if javac.exe worked instead of just javac as the compiler is actually named javac.exe. But I still think that the JDK home directory is not on your search path.